# Select colum1, column2 from table where value=somevalue

Tags: php, html, mysql, while-loop

I want to select two columns value and use them with while, i tried but failed. new to php&Mysql..

Mytable = categories ↓

```
subcat1    |   subcat2   |   category  |
=======================================
High school| Pvt School  |   Education |
---------------------------------------
Jr College | Voc College |   Education |
```

=======================================

### My Query:

```
sql="select distinct subcat1, subcat2 from categories where category='Education'";
$category=mysql_query($sql);

    <?php
       while ($cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($category))
    {
    ?>

    <a href="Category.php"> <?php echo $cat['subcat']; ?></a>
```

### Output I want to get :

> High School
>
> Pvt School
>
> Jr College
>
> Voc College

Please Help me out.. ♥ Hearty Thanks ♥

Comment: You're echoing out `subcat` but your keys are `subcat1` and `subcat2`

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 1):

echo both values inside while loop

```
<?php
    while ($cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($category)) { ?>
        <?php if($cat['subcat1']) { ?>
            <a href="Category.php"> <?php echo $cat['subcat1']; ?></a>
        <?php } if($cat['subcat1']) { ?>
            <a href="Category.php"> <?php echo $cat['subcat2']; ?></a>
        <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You deserved to achieve ♥ from OP.

Comment: I tried this.. Actually if any selected don't have any value, It Showing like this..

<li>Pvt School</li>
<li> </li>

Comment: you want to put condition to remove blank `<li>`??

Comment: is it ok?? @NiranjanNRaju  ,  as i think this column should be ckecked with empty since it will contain either string or emty string never going to be contain bool ..

Comment: at any cost, even the column is empty or null, we will get that index from query result, so it should work fine..

Answer (score 0):

Dour your stuff like below-

```
while ($cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($category))
{
    ?>
    <?php
        if($cat['subcat1']!="") {
        ?>
            <a href="Category.php"> <?php echo $cat['subcat1']; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php
        if($cat['subcat2']!="") {
        ?>
            <a href="Category.php"> <?php echo $cat['subcat2']; ?></a>
     ?php } ?>
<?php } //while close ?>
```

**OR**  better to modify your query only as

```
sql="select distinct subcat1, subcat2 from categories 
     where category='Education' AND subcat1<>'' AND subcat2<>''";
```

Comment: Something went wrong... Programme not working, showing blank page.. I tried little modifications but :(

Comment: specify errors you got.. and what about modifications ??

Comment: No Errors.. Just showing blank..

Source :
----------
<a href="category.php"> </a>

Comment: did you change your query too?? go through either of above answer .. either check it in loop or change your query .. don't do both